# JavaFX ToggleGroup Unset

Tags: javafx, toggle, togglebutton

i have some Toggle Buttons, now its needed to unset the toggle group. How can I do that?

The Problem at the moment is, that I programmend a Toggle Listener and thats the reason, why I have to unset the Toggle Group from the Toggle Button while the programm is running.

```
    ToggleGroup triangleGroup= new ToggleGroup();
    m_popupSwitch.setToggleGroup(triangleGroup);
 m_popupSwitch2.setToggleGroup(triangleGroup);
```

This is my start of the Program, i add some ToggleButtons to a ToggleGroup.

In the program i would like to destroy the connection between the ToggleGroup and some ToggleButtons

Thanks for your help :)

Greetings

Comment: What do you mean by "unset the toggle group"?

Comment: @James_D I mean that i've added a ToggleGroup to a lot of ToggleButtons. Now i want to deactivate this ToggleGroup for some of the ToggleButtons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
toggleGroup.getToggles().remove(someToggleButton);
```

do what you want?